# Invalid value for key attachdbfilename&500 - Internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

this is my connection string on godaddy hosting. By the way I have my database and membership database I makes security for some pages on my website.

All tables in one database Waves database. I used it to make login page for admin panel for my website but when I try to login and write pass & username  it makes error that I write it above and this my connection string in `web.config` .also i have another 2 connection strings but it works OK, only this connection string is not working.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=180.000.004.53\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=false;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         User ID=id;Password=Password;Encrypt=False; 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

     <add name="WavesEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.WaveModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.WaveModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.WaveModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=004.00.004.03;User ID=id;Password=password;Encrypt=False;Connect Timeout=15;Initial Catalog=Waves;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

    <add name="WavesConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=000.100.10.0;User ID=id;Password=password;Encrypt=False;Connect Timeout=15;Initial Catalog=Waves;Integrated Security=false" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: No connection string came through. See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for proper sql server connection strings. Make sure they support the exact sql server you are using, not all host support features such as attachdbfilename.

Comment: Which connection string is not working, you have posted 3, and in what way is it not working. I don't think 000.100.10.0 is a valid ip address.

Comment: the first one yes not valid but i have avalid ip the problem with AttachDBFilename not valid

Comment: Verify with GoDaddy that you can actually do the SqlServer Express with a file attached db. Not all hosts allow this approach and in fact, most don't.

Answer (score 1):

After a minor reformatting of your code, it seems pretty obvious that the first connection string is invalid, and may be causing your problem:

This part should presumably be placed within the quotes, and be part of the connection string:

```
User ID=id;Password=Password;Encrypt=False;
```